# Are there centrally-symmetric self-dual polytopes in dimension $d> 4$?

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, duality, polyhedra

A *convex* polytope $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ is *centrally symmetric* if $-P=P$. It is *self-dual* (or better, self-polar?) if its polar dual $P^\circ$ is congruent to $P$, that is, there is a map $X\in\mathrm O(\smash{\Bbb R^d})$ with $\smash{P^\circ}=XP$.

> **Question:** Are there centrally symmetric self-dual polytopes in dimension $d>4$?

Such exist in dimension $d=2$ and $d=4$:

- for $d=2$ we have the regular 2n-gons,
- for $d=4$ we have the regular 24-cell.

Comment: Had you check this text? It does not seem to be about centrally symmetrical polytopes, but about self-dual. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00784

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes. The paper mainly deals with the case $P^\circ=-P$ (then $P$ cannot be centrally symmetric). The two mentioned constructions, pyramids and joins, do not yield centrally symmetric polytopes either. The add-and-cut construction works only if we already have a self-polar polytope in dimension $d>4$.

Comment: what is $X$ for a 24-cell?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I guess I *could* compute the matrix explicitly. This would take me some time. Why do you want to know? Do you doubt its existence?

Comment: I do not doubt, but it could (theoretically) somehow suggest other examples.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Let $P$ be the convex hull of the $24$ units in the ring of half integer quaternions. Let $Q$ be the convex hull of the $24$ integer quaternions with norm $2$. Then $P$ and $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} Q$ are dual polytopes, each of which is isomorphic to the $24$-cell. Multiplication (either left or right) by $\tfrac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ is an isomorphism from $P$ to $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} Q$.

Comment: I think that, with the standard inner product, the actual statement should be that $\sqrt[4]{2} P$ and $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} Q$ are dual; the isomorphism is still given by multiplication by $\tfrac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are centrally symmetric self-dual polytopes in every dimension. This follows from Proposition 3.9 in
*Reisner, S.*, [**Certain Banach spaces associated with graphs and CL-spaces with 1- unconditional bases**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-43.1.137), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 43, No. 1, 137-148 (1991). [ZBL0757.46030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0757.46030).

Moreover, in dimension $\geqslant 3$ the matrix $X$ can be chosen to be a permutation matrix.

Here is an example in dimension $3^d$ for every $d$. Start with Sztencel-Zaramba polytope $P$. This is the unit ball for the norm on $\mathbf{R}^3$
$$ \|(x,y,z)\| = \max \left( |y|+|z|, |x|+\frac 12 |z| \right)$$
whose dual norm satisfies
$$ \|(x,y,z)\|_* = \|(z,y,x)\|. $$
We may now define inductively a sequence $\|\cdot\|_d$, which is norm on $\mathbf{R}^{3^d}$ (identified with $\mathbf{R}^{3^{d-1}}\times\mathbf{R}^{3^{d-1}}\times\mathbf{R}^{3^{d-1}}$). Chose $\|\cdot\|_1$ to be above norm, and use the recursive formula
$$ \|(x,y,z)\|_{d+1} = \|( \|x\|_d ,\|y\|_d , \|z\|_d )\|_1 .$$
One checks by induction that there is a permutation matrix which maps the unit ball onto its polar.

To visualize the polytope $P$ you may use the Sage code

```
p1 = Polyhedron(vertices=[[0,1,1],[0,1,-1],[0,-1,1],[0,-1,-1],[1,0,1/2],[1,0,-1/2],[-1,0,1/2],[-1,0,-1/2]])
p1.projection().plot()
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank your for this answer. I had already mentally excluded the possibility that I could have overlooked an example in dimension three.

Comment: Allowing for nonconvex polytopes, there are even uniform examples in (at least) 7D and 8D.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon another way to construct *many* self-dual (actually self-polar) centrally symmetric polytopes in higher dimensions.

Start from a graph $G$ on vertex set $[d]:=\{1,...,d\}$ and consider the following polytope (where $e_i$ is the $i$-th unit normal vector):

$$\mathcal P(G):=\mathrm{conv}\Big\{\sum_{i\in I} \pm e_i\;\Big\vert\;\text{$I\subseteq[d]$ induces a complete subgraph in $G$}\Big\}.$$

The $\pm$ means to consider all $2^{|I|}$ sums with all combinations of $+$ and $-$ so that the resulting polytope is centrally symmetric, in fact, coordinate symmetric (i.e. invariant under reflection at any coordinate hyperplane). This is also known as an *unconditional polytope* in the literature.

By a result due to Lovász, $G$ is a [perfect graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph#:%7E:text=Article%20Talk,and%20in%20every%20induced%20subgraph.) if and only if $(\mathcal P(G))^\circ=\mathcal P(\overline G)$, where $\overline G$ denotes the complement of $G$. Thus, if $G$ is perfect and self-complementary, we constructed a centrally symmetric self-dual (actually, self-polar) polytope in dimension $d$.
The smallest (non-trivial) example is a 4-dimensional polytope $\mathcal P(P_3)$, where $P_3$ is the path of length three (with four vertices). Considering this [list of small self-complementary graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-ComplementaryGraph.html) there is exactly one further polytope in dimension $d=5$ based on the [*bull graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bull_graph).
According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452049/108884) there seem to exist many self-complementary perfect graphs. But note that self-complementary graphs require $d\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$, and so this technique cannot construct polytopes in dimension $2,3,6,7,...$.

---

**Some references**

- L. Lovász. *"Normal hypergraphs and the perfect graph conjecture"*
- F. Kohl, M. Olsen, R. Sanyal. *"Unconditional reflexive polytopes"*